# Extend Spring security OAuth2 to store additional client data

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using spring security OAuth2. I was wondering if I there is any easy/clean way to extend spring OAuth2 module to storing additional information associated with that client e.g, Email Id associated to the client and retrieve this in OAuth2Authentication.

I explored ClientDetailsService and AuthorizationRequest, but looks like there is no easy way to achieve this without overriding a whole bunch of classes. A quick Google search did not help either.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem? Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Ouath2 provide  [JdbcClientDetailsService](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2/1.0.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/JdbcClientDetailsService.java). It looks for oauth_client_details  table.

You can create your own class with your own table name and column names.

```
<beans:bean id="clientDetails"
    class="MyOwnClass">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" /></beans:bean>
```

Provide the reference of above bean wherever you need client details something like this

`<oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="**clientDetails**" token-services-ref="tokenServices" user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code disabled="true" />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token disabled="true" />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password disabled="true" />
    </oauth:authorization-server>`

```
    <beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="com.mkyong.common.controller.SparklrUserApprovalHandler">
    <beans:property name="approvalStore" ref="approvalStore" />
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="**clientDetails**" />
    <beans:property name="requestFactory" ref="defaultOAuth2RequestFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: thanks. it's weird that it looks for table with key as id. what if the user changes the email address?

Comment: Did u get anything on this.